# I want to get a href link from a tag using beautiful soup from HTML website

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping this product page: https://www.hugoboss.com/us/interlock-cotton-t-shirt-with-exclusive-artwork/hbna50487153_739.html

I want the links of each color of this product from this HTML code:[image]

Current code:

```
 import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    import time 
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
    from selenium import webdriver 
    import time
    import requests
    
    driverfile = r'C:\Users\Main\Documents\Work\Projects\Scraping Websites\extra\chromedriver'
    
    #driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    
    url = "https://www.hugoboss.com/us/interlock-cotton-t-shirt-with-exclusive-artwork/hbna50487153_739.html"
    
    def make_soup(url):
      page = requests.get(url)
      page_soup = soup(page.content, 'lxml')
      return page_soup 
    
    product_page_soup = make_soup(url)
    print(product_page_soup.select('a.slides__slide slides__slide--color-selector.js-slide.js- 
    product-swatch.widget-initialized'))

`
```

Current output: is an empty list `[]`

Expected Output: HTML of the a tag

FYI: Selecting another A tag on the same product page works e.g: `print(product_page_soup.select('a.dch-links-item.dch-links-item--released.dch-links-item--unstyled-selector.dch-links-item--bold--underscore.dch-links-item-tracking')[0].text.strip())`  : This outputs desired text using the same method so I am confused why it would not work for a tag in question `'a.slides__slide slides__slide--color-selector.js-slide.js-  product-swatch.widget-initialized'`

I also tried using `product_page_soup.findAll ('a', {"class":'slides__slide.slides__slide--color-selector.js-slide.js-product-swatch.widget-initialized'})` but got the same empty list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following CSS expression with bs4 will grab the desired links

```
[class="stage__left-wrapper"] div nav a')
```

Full working code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get('https://www.hugoboss.com/us/interlock-cotton-t-shirt-with-exclusive-artwork/hbna50487153_739.html')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
for u in soup.select('[class="stage__left-wrapper"] div nav a'):
    link = 'https://www.hugoboss.com' + u.get('href')
    print(link)
```

**Output:**

```
https://www.hugoboss.com/us/interlock-cotton-t-shirt-with-exclusive-artwork/hbna50487153_739.html
https://www.hugoboss.com/us/interlock-cotton-t-shirt-with-exclusive-artwork/hbna50487153_100.html
https://www.hugoboss.com/us/interlock-cotton-t-shirt-with-exclusive-artwork/hbna50487153_001.html
```

Answer (score 1):

In page source link has @class `"widget"`. I guess it replaced with `"widget-initialized"` after page rendered. So try

```
.widget
```

instead of

```
.widget-initialized
```

And so complete selector should be

```
a.slides__slide.slides__slide--color-selector.js-slide.js-product-swatch.widget
```

Also for better readability I would recommend to use CSS selector

```
'nav > a[data-as-click="productClick"]'
```

Comment: how do I find the page source?

Comment: @user13174343 in Browser right click on page -> View Page Source